# Blazor: listing and linking local HTML files from Blazor page

Tags: c#, html, blazor

I need to list HTML files from a machine running a Blazor-Server. The HTML pages are generated by another app. I am able to retrieve all HTML file names and list them on the Blazor page (creating a `<a href="file:///path_to_local_html_file">actual_file_name</a>` for each HTML file found). However, when clicking on the links to the HTML files on my Blazor page nothing happens. When I RMB on the link and select `Open link in new tab` it only loads an empty page with an address of `about:blank#blocked`.

I have not that much experience with Blazor, but I guess it is some kind of protection to not access files and directories outside of the Blazor page scope.

My Blazor server comes from this MSDN tutorial and is working: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/aspnet/blazor-tutorial/run

My own code is as follows (added in `Index.razor`):

```
<p>@((MarkupString)myString)</p>

@code {
    private string myString = LoadFiles();
    private static string LoadFiles()
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        foreach (var file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Temp"))
        {
            sb.AppendLine($"<a href=\"file:///{file.Replace(@"\", "/")}\" target=\"_blank\">{file}</a><br/>");
        }
        foreach (var folder in System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Temp"))
        {
            sb.AppendLine($"<p>{folder}</p>");
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Blazor app is located in `C:\projects\BlazorApp`, HTML files are located in `C:\Temp` on same machine.

**How to create a working link to those HTML files in a Blazor page?**

- *I have no control over the app creating the HTML files, so I only can check if there are files available or not. If available, as described, I need to link them.*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since no one answered you yet - high level overview: You can't access the file system to read anything from the C drive from inside Blazor, because Blazor scopes your actions to the webpage inside the browser window. You will have to read the HTML via the server application and send the HTML to the Blazor front-end, which will then have to accept and render that HTML.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Displaying the file content is so simple that I did not think of that. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to JeremyW I will read the content of the files and display that as `MarkupString`. Therefore I prepared a page which receives a full file path as parameter (in URL) and then reads the file.

```
@inject NavigationManager navManager
@((MarkupString)htmlContent)
@code {
    private string htmlContent = "";
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        var URL_PARAMS = GetURLParameters(navManager);
        htmlContent = ReadHtmlFile(URL_PARAMS);
    }
}
```

Inside the HTML files there are additional links to other local files. So I update those links before passing the actual content to the `htmlContent` variable. Each of those links now point to the same blazor page, again providing the file path to the file as parameter.

`http://localhost:44444/readFilePage?fullPath=C%3a\Files%3a\data.html`