# Link to html page not working in live server/Blazor Wasm App but is working locally in debug?

Tags: c#, routes, blazor-webassembly

I am developing a Blazor WASM application and need to add some external links to e.g. a cookies page which I am putting in a seperate tab using:

```
<a href="/Legal/Cookies.html" class="b-bar-link" target="_blank">
  Cookies
</a>
```

Obviously with a Web assembly blazor app, most of it is loaded on to the client, but I don't think I have quite got my head around objects that still live on the client vs the server.
Images etc. stay on the server in the wwwroot folder. So I thought I should be able to create a /Legal folder in wwwroot and put the files there. These docs might change often so I figured better there.

So my folders look like most wasm template projects:
[image]

When I use the link to get to the cookies page, it works fine in VS under debug, but in the live server is heading to the 'Page not found'.

I am using an Azure AppService, and initially thought that maybe the problem may be due to a publishing/build issue. So I checked and the file properties all have 'copy always' as their
content action. Also, I checked the server published files and they are there.

I realise that the VS debug environment is using a cut down IIS and is different to the main Azure one, so I wondered if it could be permissions related. Suggestions please.?

*EDIT*
I think this is as someone suggested a routing issue. But does anyone know how to have  Blazor Wasm mixed with the occasional file on the server? I mean, the default Identity stuff that MS provides does that very thing, though it is hard to figure out... any pointers to a doc? Thanks.

Comment: This sounds more like a routing issue to me. Do you have something like www.myweb.com/something/else/here ?

Comment: I agree that it sounds like routing, but I am not sure exactly what you mean? Yes, the page is URL/Legal/Cookies.html and on my m/c is localhost:####/Legal...
I get that I need to understand routing better, any pointers to a simple doc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question here in case anyone else falls into this particular set of traps..

I was guided to some extent by a sort of similar question:
[blazor-listing-and-linking-local-html-files-from-blazor-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67157719/blazor-listing-and-linking-local-html-files-from-blazor-page)

It wasn't a routing problem as such, more a mis-understanding on my part of how a Blazor app is structured, and that it can't easily switch in an out of being a Single Page App...

Anyway, I am using Blazorise to help with my UI so I constructed a 'Popup' page to handle this sort of thing, like this:

```
<Modal @ref="modalRef">
<ModalContent IsCentered="true" Size="ModalSize.ExtraLarge">
    <ModalHeader>
        <CloseButton Clicked="@HideModal" />
    </ModalHeader>
    <ModalBody Style="min-height: 50vh">
        @htmlContent
    </ModalBody>
</ModalContent>
</Modal>
```

This with the code page to activate the popup and get the data as follows:

```
    [Inject] FileService _fileService { get; set; }

    Modal? modalRef = new Modal();

    [Parameter]
    public string urlPath {get; set;}

    private MarkupString htmlContent= new MarkupString();

    private async Task GetContent()
    {
        htmlContent = (MarkupString) await _fileService.GetServerFileString(urlPath); 
    }

    public async Task ShowModal(string? url = null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
        {
            urlPath = url;
        }
        await GetContent();
        modalRef.Show();
    }
    public void HideModal()
    {
        modalRef.Hide();
    }
```

The _fileService function being:

```
    public async Task<string> GetServerFileString(string serverURL)
    {
        string content = await HttpPublic.GetStringAsync(serverURL);
        return content;
    }
```

Then to use it in a page, (I am actually referencing straight from the MainLayout) it is as easy as:

```
       <Button @onclick='() => ShowPopup("/Legal/Privacy.html")'>Privacy</Button>
```

or

```
<Button @onclick='() => ShowPopup("/Legal/Cookies.html")'>Cookies</Button>
```

With the code function being:

```
    protected async void ShowPopup(string url)
    { 
        await htmlPopup.ShowModal(url);
    }
```

I did it that way because I am using the component several times in the same page... Given the Parameter function, you could also do it by just referencing the component and passing the param.

Hope this helps someone else. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You should look at this for hosting: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#app-base-path

> In many hosting scenarios, the relative URL path to the app is the root of the app. In these default cases, the app's relative URL base path is the following:

```
Blazor WebAssembly: / configured as <base href="/" />.
Blazor Server: ~/ configured as <base href="~/" />.
```

> In other hosting scenarios, such as GitHub Pages and IIS sub-apps, the app base path must be set to the server's relative URL path of the app.

See the rest of the article for how to adapt to your scenario. In short, you can include your path in `launchSettings.json` and have different configurations based on your dev/production environments.

Also take a look at the following article for absolute url handling inside your app if required: https://swimburger.net/blog/dotnet/how-to-generate-absolute-urls-in-aspdotnet-core

Comment: OK thank you, so I've read that, but tbh it seems to be geared to where to position the root of the app.  The swimburger blog is great but just deals with generating urls. I know the URL and it works in debug mode on my local machine. (Or is that more by luck than judgement?).  My base is set to the default "/" and I am not trying to do anything fancy, just load an html page in a new tab...  what am I missing?