# How to Route back to the server for pages in a Blazor Webassembly app?

Tags: c#, razor-pages, blazor-webassembly

I have (sort of) asked this before. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75483131/link-to-html-page-not-working-in-live-server-blazor-wasm-app-but-is-working-loca/75512394#75512394), but in a different context and I managed to work around the issue without really solving it. Now I need to.

I want to add a Payment Provider 'Drop In' to my app. This is a black box object but requires API Keys and other sensitive information best kept on the server. So I need to go from my (working) Blazor web assembly app to a page back in the server.

I am using Identity so the server already handles MVC style pages but I really don't care if  I use razor or MVC.. more comfortable with razor I guess... but this is in my Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(
options => options.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes = true
);

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
```

I mean I guess this must be some routing stuff I haven't figured out? If I add the file e.g. Payment.cshtml as a razor page to the folder 'Pages' on the server, I kinda hope it 'would just work'... no such luck.

Any pointers?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you have `app.MapRazorPages(); app.MapControllers(); app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");` in your `Program.cs`?

Comment: Yes, i do...

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();

Comment: I am guessing but does that add in the mapping needed for what I want..?

Comment: ... and my other guess was that the 'Payment.cshtml' under yhe root folder of Pages in the server should work with Localhost:xxxx/Payment.cshtml as the uri?

Comment: The url hould be `localhost:xxxx/Payment`. Have you also created the `Payment.cshtml.cs` page model? The Blazor WASM hosted project template already has razor pages configured and already has the Pages folder with `Error.cshtml` page. Just check the Error page and create your own page similarly.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look tomorrow 

Comment: See these three sites on multi site hosting - 1, -  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5299017/Building-a-Blazor-WASM-and-Server-All-In-One-Solut 2, - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5321697/Building-a-Blazor-Server-Application-from-the-Web 3. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5287009/Blazor-Hydra-Hosting-Multiple-Blazor-SPAs-on-a-sin

Comment: Thank you all, yes, fixing the URL sorted it. I think I must have bee mixing it up with the mvc pages in the Identity stuff...